# How to spawn ghci and pass a pointer to it where it can access later?

Tags: haskell, process

In my haskell program I invoke ghci via `createProcess` in System.Process module. I want to run some initialization code in ghci before entering in a forever loop which gets user input and passes to ghci for evaluation. One of the value is a `Ptr a` which is created using FFI from c code. Another is a function which is imported from shared lib which needs the pointer to do all useful stuffs. I can "create" this function directly in ghci or make ghci load a module file, but the pointer is the key problem.

That pointer actually points to a large struct and is volatile. Ideally to make it works ghci should be able to access the memory at any time. I'm not familiar with Linux process and don't know if it's possible in this scenario. Or is there any better way to achieve the same effect? (create a repl environment with additional helper functions ready for the user to use interactively)

I prefer not to write my own repl code and not use hint.

Comment: I could be way off but my understanding is that on modern systems there's no feasible way to pass and use a pointer between processes as each get's it's own [virtualized] address space. I think you would need to set up a communication channel where read/write requests are transmitted and executed within the owner of that memory. If both processes do not need access to the data structure, can you serialize the contents? Have you looked into something like: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/As_a_library instead of spawning a different process?

Comment: You can create a shared-memory region, and the OS will ensure that the two processes' virtual memory spaces map that region to the same physical memory. If you can convince the C code to accept a pointer and initialize itself there, rather than letting C create the pointer with malloc and give it back to you, this could be a possible solution.

Comment: Kind of a hack, but can you pass `:l MyFancyModule` and `ptr <- myFancyInitializationRoutine` to ghci's stdin?

Comment: @ryachza Initially I was looking for some features like tab completion in a relative easy way, that's why I went to invoking ghci. For the ptr problem maybe ghc API (or hint) is the way to go. I will look into the doc in detail.

Comment: @amalloy Unfortunately I can't. The haskell program is actually acting like a "language plugin" for the original c program. It will be compiled to a shared library and exposing a "plugin" structure defining functions like init, prompt, run, etc. The C program will `dlopen` it at runtime and call those functions at some time.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes I can but from my understanding ghci can't still access the memory area even if it gets the value of the pointer. (Actually I tried casting it to `IntPtr` and pass the int value, then convert back to `Ptr a` in ghci. This doesn't work, as expected...)

Comment: Rather than use a GHCi process, perhaps, you should look in to hint (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint). You can pass it pointers by casting them to string representations of the pointer value.